# Javascript yyyy-mm-dd converting to incorrect date (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: javascript

Here is the code where the user enters a date: (it has to be a date picker on my end, but the form has to submit the date field as text – don’t ask)

On submit, I call validation logic in javascript. I’ve attached a screenshot of what it looks like when I try to enter 01/01/2001 as the users birthday. It looks like when I’m converting the value string to a Date object, it’s converting to the wrong date and time. If it would just convert correctly, I could adjust the month and day and year and build a string to send in my second object.

Attaching the picture…

I’ve messed around with UTC and timezones, but to no avail.

I need my output to be a text string "01/01/2001" which I can build as long as I have the correct date going in..but it seems to calculate wrong no matter what I try.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a jquery datapicker library did the trick.

```
function initDatePickers() {
jQuery('.om-datepicker-trigger').click(function () {
    var defaultDatePickerOptions = {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        defaultDate: '-45y',
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            var widget = jQuery(inst).datepicker('widget');
            widget.css('margin-left', jQuery(input).outerWidth() + 3 - 
widget.outerWidth());
        },
        //buttonImage: "/img/button_calendar.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        showOn: "both"
    };

    var $input = jQuery(this).parent().find('.om-input-date').first();

    if ($input.hasClass('om-min-date-today')) {
        var minDateTodayOptions = defaultDatePickerOptions;
        minDateTodayOptions.defaultDate = 0;
        minDateTodayOptions.minDate = 0;
        $input.datepicker(minDateTodayOptions);
        $input.datepicker('show');
    } else {
        $input.datepicker(defaultDatePickerOptions);
        $input.datepicker('show');
    }
});

jQuery('.om-input-date').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).next('.om-datepicker-trigger').trigger('click');
});


// Datepicker
// --------------------------------------------------------
jQuery('.om-input-date').keyup(function () {
    var inputDOBBox = jQuery(this);
    var dateValue = inputDOBBox.attr('value');
    if (dateValue.length == 3 || dateValue.length == 6) {
        var first = dateValue.substring(0, dateValue.length - 1);
        var last = dateValue.substring(dateValue.length - 1);
        if (last != "/" && last != "-") {
            inputDOBBox.attr('value', first + "/" + last);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the Date it is assumed that the string represents a time in UTC since no timezone was provided. The string is parsed as UTC, but the Date object uses your browser's local timezone.

One way to fix that is to use [getUTCDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) instead of `getDay`. Same applies to [month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) and [year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear).